# Is Rovelli's argument a compelling argument for baby universes?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, holographic-principle, black-hole-thermodynamics

A [Recent Rovelli's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.00218) argues that black hole states accessible in the interior exceed those that are given by the holographic bound observed externally.

It seems that in principle, right before Hawking evaporation, those extra states would persist and technically result in a baby universe. Is there a way to escape this conclusion?

Comment: Rovelli doesn't address the issue of what would happen right at the final stage of the evaporation, right? He just mentions that one can have large volume even with a small area but I am afraid that argument has to break down as one approaches the really final stages of the evaporation.

Comment: Also, don't you think that Rovelli is just re-stating the Information Paradox?

Answer (score 2):

This is to state that you should think that Rovelli's argument demands baby universes if and only if you think the good old Information Paradox also demands the same.

I first thought that Rovelli's paper is beautiful, he seems to suggest something so simple and yet seemingly profound. But then, on a second thought, I think the paper is nearly vacuous, the paper can be interpreted as either a restatement of the Information Paradox or as a set of mistaken arguments IMHO.

See, what Rovelli is telling us is that the information that goes inside the BH should be preserved (via his Cauchy surface and light cone construction) and thus, even with a decreasing area, the entropy must not decrease.

First of all, this seems wrong to me because I think that the possibility of information leaving the BH via Hawking radiation has been strongly suggested by many people. It is nearly well-established that the Hawking radiation is not purely thermal. It has long-range correlations and contains information.

Secondly, if one considers the possibility of Hawking radiation being thermal and containing no information at all then the scenario just becomes a statement of the Information Paradox: Due to the decreasing area, the information contained by the BH is decreasing and we are not recovering that information anywhere - pure states are going to thermal states. The argument that there should be some ''interior states'' over and above the ones accounted by the Beckenstein-Hawking entropy seems like inconsistent wishful thinking motivated by the urge to preserve the information. But it clearly doesn't work. Any claim of the possibility of the apparently lost information being secretly encoded into these additional ''interior states'' loses its charm as soon as the BH completely evaporates in a finite amount of time - leaving no interior at all. If you still want to stick to this line of thought then maybe you can say that right at the moment of the complete evaporation, all the interior states form a baby universe but then certainly it violates the unitarity in our universe. So, I would simply ask - "Is it worth it?".

Comment: The possibility that the baby universes might "leave no interior at all", upon their Hawking evaporation, seems to overlook the possibility that the baby universes might meanwhile have had baby universes of their own, etc., ad infinitum.  (I recollect hearing of some expectation of Rovelli's that the divisibility of space might have a limit, but I believe his thoughts may have evolved since, and, in fact, he mentions some evolution of them even in the paper Lurscher cited.)